# Failed to fetch an API

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm fetching an API from the OMDB API and I get this output `(TypeError: Failed to fetch)`.

I tested the API with Postman and I got a Positive response. My App has a inputbox and a search button only! It should display the movies when a user inputs a title.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  //state that stores the movies fetched from imdb database
  state = {
    movies: []
  }
  //sendRequest function that uses unirest to get our movie information. 
  sendRequest = (Title) => {
    const req = unirest("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=275a2eec");
    req.query({
      "page": "1",
      "r": "json",
      "s": Title
    });
    req.headers({
      "x-rapidapi-host": "The OMDb API",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "275a2eec"
    });
    req.end((res) => {
      if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
      //We’re pulling our movies out of the response data, and storing them in our app state.
      const movies = res.body.Search;
      this.setState({
        movies
      });
      console.log(res.body);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in response headers. If they dont match then react's fetch API can throw that error.

Comment: How please?I totally don't understand

Comment: do a [get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4881836/3509874) req

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, we get this error when `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` of response header and origin of request won't match.

Check out this [article](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b) for a detailed explanation.

If you're testing this application on localhost you may try changing the `http` to `https`. This is the simple solution that sometimes works in this type of errors.